# Using Variables to Trigger Definitions

Tags: python

Super new to python so this may be silly, but I'm having some trouble using variables to trigger definitions. Essentially I am making a simple video game with a Raspberry Pi and Sense Hat and am trying to store different sections of my game in definitions so that I can easily order them.

I've simplified the code to just show the logic I'm having an issue with Here I am adding 1 to the seq variable at the end of each defined sequence (which just sets pixels on the LED matrix), then using if statements to execute different definitions based on the value of seq. The issue is it won’t execute any of the code after the first definition.

Any help is appreciated and please let me know if this is posted in the wrong place or format so that I can fix it (first time posting).

```
import time
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep

sense = SenseHat()

b = (0, 102, 102) # blue
w = (200, 200, 200) # White
y = (204, 204, 0) # Yellow
e = (0, 0, 0) # Empty
gr = (0,100,0)
g = (0,250,0)

startScreen = [
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    e, e, w, e, e, e, e, e,
    e, e, w, w, w, e, e, e,
    e, e, w, w, w, w, e, e,
    e, e, w, w, w, w, e, e,
    e, e, w, w, w, e, e, e,
    e, e, w, e, e, e, e, e,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e
]

judge = [
    e, e, e, w, w, e, e, e,
    e, e, w, w, w, w, e, e,
    e, e, w, w, w, w, e, e,
    e, e, e, w, w, e, e, e,
    e, e, b, w, w, b, e, e,
    e, b, b, b, b, b, b, e,
    e, b, b, b, b, b, b, e,
    e, b, b, b, b, b, b, e
]

seq = 0

while True:

    def test():
        sense.set_pixels(startScreen)
        sleep(1)
        seq = 1
    
    def test2():        
        sense.clear()
        sense.set_pixels(judge)
   
    if seq == 0:
        test()
    
    if seq == 1:
        test2()
```

Comment: The `seq` that you are setting inside `test()` is a *local variable*, completely unrelated to the global `seq` that you are testing elsewhere.  Putting `global seq` inside the function would be one solution.

Comment: Having the “def”s inside the loop means you are creating new functions every time through which is probably not what you want to do